# Why stage manager autohide?

Tags: ventura, stage-manager

Video of the problem:
Removed

I'm running macOS Ventura (13.0) on a MacBook Air M1 8-core CPU/GPU and 16GB of RAM

Comment: Please don't ask us to watch a video. It doesn't explain the problem to those who may be using the search facility for a similar problem, and the question goes stale when the link goes stale. Please try to explain the problem in words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should only hide the thumbnails if your window covers it (just like on iPad): https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT213315

> If a window covers thumbnails, the thumbnails hide until you uncover them or move the pointer to the left edge of the screen.

Have you checked the settings (see linked documentation):

> Recent applications
>
> Turned on: Thumbnails remain visible, unless covered by a window.

You can try to reset Stage Manager settings this way:

```
defaults delete com.apple.WindowManager; killall WindowManager;
```